# How can I unninstall/install program, in c# code?

Tags: c#

How can I unninstall/install program, in c# code? and how the installation can run automatic without involved from an user? can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There a couple of ways you can do this. I'll cover the installation, but both methods allow uninstallation and repairs in the same way.

- You should use the [Windows Installer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372860(v=VS.85).aspx). For example, [MsiInstallProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370315(v=VS.85).aspx) allows you to programmatically kick off an install. [Pinvoke.net reference for the same function](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msi.MsiInstallProduct) (so you can use this native function from managed code).
- You can call the msiexec utility with the location of the MSI you wish to install, via Process.Start(). I would recommend the API approach over this.

> msiexec.exe /i `<msi-location>` /l*v `<log-location>`

Comment: The Windows Installer API is an unmanaged API, C# doesn't provide functionality to call out to Windows Installer by default. I can update the post with some example code if that will help?

Comment: this is my code:
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i \"C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\flashmx_trial_en.exe\"/qn";
            p.Start();
the program doesn't installer.
do you have example code that work well?
Thanks

Comment: That is not an MSI, to kick off the installation for that application you would just need to start the EXE. However, that would start it in an interactive mode, so the user would still have to click buttons on the UI to progress. There may be a flag to install it silently, but you would have to check the docs. Are you trying to write code that can potentially install any application or just one particular application? If the answer is the former, this can get very complex with regards to arguments to pass to different executables and setting properties for different MSIs.

Comment: do you have example code of install any application that work well?

Comment: As I said, the scenario becomes much more complex if this is the case. Each installer behaves differently and may expect different arguments, especially if you throw EXEs into the mix. You would have to write code that processes some metadata for the individual installer and acts accordingly. I can't provide an example to that extent.