# How can I get the data about uninstall of a program?

Tags: c#

How can I get the data about uninstall of a program?
this is my code:

```
private void uninstallSoftware() 
{ 
  Process p = new Process(); 
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"; 
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x \"??????\"/qn"; 
  p.Start();
```

}

For example: 
I want to uninstall a Lan driver, the program currently displays in  programs and features list.

How can I uninstall it from c# code?

Comment: What OS, XP and Vista has different ways of doing this.

Comment: Check out this link... http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10069013/uninstall-a-proram-by-using-c.aspx  it has an example using registry and  WMI

Comment: Possbile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440247/how-can-i-unninstall-install-program-in-c-code/3440302#3440302

Comment: Do not know what you think, but I need an answer to this question